# The difference between the attribute name, value and path of the annotation @RequestMapping in SpringMVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I am struggling to understand the differences between the attribute `name`, `path` and `value` in `@RequestMapping`. I looked into the API, but it doesn't illustrate it clearly. I googled for hours but it just works partially. Can you tell me the details? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see the javadoc. Start with path:

> The path mapping URIs (e.g. "/profile").

So that's the path(s) that will be used by Spring to decide if this methd should be called or not, based on the actual path of the request.

Now value:

> The primary mapping expressed by this annotation.
>
> This is an alias for path(). For example, @RequestMapping("/foo") is equivalent to @RequestMapping(path="/foo").

So, it's quite clear: value and path are exactly equivalent.

And finally name:

> Assign a name to this mapping.

So this is completely different. It gives a name to this mapping. Why could a name be useful for a mapping? You can discover that by clicking on the "See also" classes linked to attrbibute in the documentation. The javadoc for HandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy says:

> Applications can build a URL to a controller method by name with the help of the static method MvcUriComponentsBuilder#fromMappingName  [...]

So, as you see, the name of a mapping can be used to construct a URL that will match to a given controller method by using the name of its mapping. That makes it possible to change the path of a mapping without changing it everywhere, by using names rather than paths.

The [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping), in addition to the javadoc, should be your first destination. This is usually way more effective when you want to learn about the framework than googling.